# Cannot pass the value to the method for delivering email using delayed job gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using an special approach to deliver email.

First, I abstract the call of method for delivering email into a control method `send_email`
Second, I delayed the execution of the control method.

It seems to be fine to send some value that are hard-coded into the method for delivering email, but not the value passed into that method.

*Control method:*

```
  # this method is being delayed to control the time of sending email
  def send_email

    # approach 1 : just send a email after method send_email is executed 
    # In delay situtation : after 2 minutes
    # Otherwise : no delay
    Notifier.create_long_task(1234).deliver

    # approach 2: explicitly states to delay sending email process 
    # (same result with the above one)
    # 
    # Notifier.delay.create_long_task(1234)
  end

  handle_asynchronously :send_email, :run_at => Proc.new { 2.minutes.from_now }
```

In the above codes, I passed 1234 into delivering method and below the delivering method will assign 1234 to an instance variable `@id`

```
 def create_long_task(longTask_id)
    @greeting = "Hi"
    @longTask ="delay setting"
    @id = longTask_id

    mail to: "j-@hotmail.com", :subject => 'Long Task Created'
  end
```

*The email template looks like :*

```
    Notifier#create_long_task
    Instance variable 1 : <%= @greeting %>
    Instance variable 2 : <%= @longTask %>
    Instance Id : <%= @id %>
    You created a long task
```

**So to be optimistic, the email will show 3 instance variables, 2 are hard-coded in the delivering method, one is passed into delivering method from outside**

**But the results only can show 2 instance variables that are hard-coded in the delivering method.**

```
Notifier#create_long_task
Instance variable 1 : Hi
Instance variable 2 : delay setting
Instance Id : 
You created a long task
```

**It is very strange.
When I comment out `handle_asynchronously` to send the email without any delay, I can see all the instance variables. So I think that 1234 cannot be passed into delivering method.
Result of no delay email just like:**

```
Notifier#create_long_task
Instance variable 1 : Hi
Instance variable 2 : delay setting
Instance Id : 1234
You created a long task
```

This is a very long,complicated problem statement, I really appreciate if anyone can solve this problem.

Comment: Just a hunch: have you been restarting delayed job after you make changes to the code ?

Comment: hhaha , no . I have just restart it and it works fine now. thx:)
But I don't get the reason.

Comment: @FrederickCheung I should thanks for your answer long time ago, leave your answer below and I can 'tick' it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to restart delayed job as it won't pick up changes to your code until you do.